# What's the latest technology to write a kiosk app for Windows 10?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I'd like to write a kiosk app for Windows 10. After UWP has been deprecated by Microsoft, I'm lost.

What's the latest way of writing an app that can be used in kiosk mode?

(NB: I would not want to publish it on Microsoft Store or Marketplace. I just want to pain install my app locally.)

Answer (score 1):

UWP has not been deprecated - it is still a great way to build a kiosk app.  [Here are the detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I got my information from here: https://www.thurrott.com/dev/206351/microsoft-confirms-uwp-is-not-the-future-of-windows-apps